# Testing Application in JUNIt

Tags: junit4

I'm getting errors while testing my application in JUNIT

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

as i created classes for Configuration and not applicationContext files it is messing up this error.

Below is classes and DAO file.

```
WebAppContext.java
package com.atoc.test.entity;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.atoc.test.DAO",
        "com.atoc.test.entity"
})
public class WebAppContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver() {
        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();

        Properties exceptionMappings = new Properties();

       // exceptionMappings.put(arg0, arg1)
       // exceptionMappings.put("net.petrikainulainen.spring.testmvc.todo.exception.TodoNotFoundException", "error/404");
        exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.Exception", "error/error");
        exceptionMappings.put("java.lang.RuntimeException", "error/error");

        exceptionResolver.setExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings);

        Properties statusCodes = new Properties();

        statusCodes.put("error/404", "404");
        statusCodes.put("error/error", "500");

        exceptionResolver.setStatusCodes(statusCodes);

        return exceptionResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
TestContext.java:
package com.atoc.test.entity;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;

import com.atoc.test.DAO.UserTestDAO;
import com.bpa.qaproduct.repository.UserDAO;

@Configuration
public class TestContext {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDAO userDAO() {
        //UserTestDAO userTestDao = new UserTestDAO();
        return Mockito.mock(UserDAO.class);
    }
}
UserTestDAO.java:
package com.atoc.test.DAO;


import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
//import org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager;
//import  org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.atoc.test.entity.TestContext;
import com.atoc.test.entity.WebAppContext;
import com.bpa.qaproduct.entity.User;
import com.bpa.qaproduct.repository.UserDAO;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class, WebAppContext.class})
public class UserTestDAO {

    @Autowired
   private UserDAO userDAO;

    private User testUser;


    @Test
    public void testGetUserFilterCount() {

        assertNotNull(userDAO);
        assertNotNull(testUser);

    int value =  userDAO.getUserFilterCount(testUser);
        assertNotNull(value);

    }
    @Test
    public void testGetUserList1() {


        assertNotNull(userDAO);
        assertNotNull(testUser);

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> list=userDAO.getUserList(testUser);
        assertNotNull(list);

    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testGetUserList() {


        List<User> listToString = userDAO.getUserList(testUser);
        assertTrue(listToString.containsAll(listToString));

    }
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testGetAllUserList() {
        List<User> listToString = userDAO.getAllUserList(testUser);
        assertTrue(listToString.containsAll(listToString));
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testGetUserById() {

        User expectedUser = new User();
        expectedUser.setUserId(1);
        expectedUser.setFirstName("Kiran");
        expectedUser.setUserEmail("kirankumar@bpatech.com");

        int userId = 1;
        User actualUser = userDAO.getUserById(userId);

        //("bpa", expectedUser.getUserEmail(),actualUser.getUserEmail());*/

    assertNotNull(actualUser);
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidateUser() {


        assertNotNull(userDAO);
        String userEmail = null;
        assertNotNull(userEmail);
        String userPassword = null;
        assertNotNull(userPassword);
        User value=userDAO.validateUser(userEmail, userPassword);
        assertNotNull(value);
        assertTrue(userDAO.validateUser(userEmail, userPassword)==null);

    }
    @Test
    public void testUpdatePassword() {

        assertNotNull(userDAO);
        String userEmail = null;
        assertNotNull(userEmail);
        String userPassword =  null;
        assertNotNull(userPassword);
        User value=userDAO.updatePassword(userEmail, userPassword);
        assertNotNull(value);
        assertTrue(userDAO.updatePassword(userEmail, userPassword) == null);
    }
    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testForgotUserPassword() {

        User expectedUser = new User();
        expectedUser.setUserId(1);
        expectedUser.setFirstName("Kiran");

        String userName="bpa";
        User actualResult=userDAO.forgotPassword(userName);
        assertEquals(actualResult.getFirstName(),expectedUser.getFirstName());
    }
    @Test
    public void testSaveUser() {



        assertTrue(true);
    }
    @Test
    public void testRemoveUser() {

        assertTrue(true);

    }

}
```

As i m using classes to configure and not XML files.Is there any way to overcome this error No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency.

Failed to load ApplicationContext is one of the base error for this.This is of full code details with the configuration files

WebAppContext and TestContext is of Configuration files

UesrTestDAO is the DAO method where my JUNIT works